# Convert JSON string to list and access 3rd element in it

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON string that looks like this:

`[["1", 1, "hy3mRUeEcb18NLC1"], {}]`

I load the string like :
`taskParams = json.loads(x.task_params)[0]`

because there are multiple JSON objects and I only want the first.

Then I try to access the third element, or in a list index the 2. index like this:

`print(taskParams[2])`

It gives me the following error:

> list index out of range

Which it is clearly not.

For clarification full code:

```
taskParams = json.loads(x.task_params)[0] 
print(taskParams[2])
```

Full output from start:

```
[["1", 1, "hy3mRUeEcb18NLC1"], {}]
[[], {}]
[[], {}]
```

Output after json.loads()

```
['1', 1, 'hy3mRUeEcb18NLC1']
```

Output i want:
`hy3mRUeEcb18NLC1`

Comment: this dosen't look like a valid json string, it looks more like a list. Is this the complete json string?

Comment: `['1', 1, 'hy3mRUeEcb18NLC1']` is not a valid JSON string. `'["1", 1, "hy3mRUeEcb18NLC1"]'` is. Please [edit] your question and provide a runnable [mre] (MRE).

Comment: What is actually in x.task_params? Maybe you want json.loads(x.task_parms[0])?

Comment: Updated correctly.
Noticed i didn't provide the original json string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string needs to be enclosed in double quotes, as per the spec at https://www.json.org/json-en.html which says:

> A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in
> double quotes, using backslash escapes. A character is represented as
> a single character string. A string is very much like a C or Java
> string.

An example of a working solution would be:

```py
import json
x = '["1", 1, "hy3mRUeEcb18NLC1"]'
taskParams = json.loads(x)
print(taskParams[2])
```

Which outputs

> hy3mRUeEcb18NLC1

For your longer JSON string you can do this:

```py
import json
x = '[["1", 1, "hy3mRUeEcb18NLC1"], {}]'
taskParams = json.loads(x)[0]
print(taskParams[2])
```